# .find() does not take a string? Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I have lately been working on a project that retrieves METAR from a NOAA website, and slices the METAR data and prints it. Now I have encountered a problem as change the code to `Python3.6`, when I try to `.find()` the marker that sates the start of the METAR data it gives me this error message:

```
File "/Users/MrZeus/Desktop/PY3.6_PROJECT/version_1.py", line 22, in daMainProgram
    data_start = website_html.find("<--DATA_START-->")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I do understand what this error is saying. It means that the `.find()` does not take a string, but according to the python docs the `.find()` function does take a string!

here is the section of code I am having trouble with:

```
website = urllib.request.urlopen(airid)

website_html = website.read()

print(website_html)

br1_string = "<!-- Data starts here -->"

data_start = website_html.find(br1_string)

br1 = data_start + 25

br2 = website_html.find("<br />")

metar_slice = website_html[br1:br2]

print("Here is the undecoded METAR data:\n"+metar_slice)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTTPResponce.read()` returns a `bytes` object. `bytes` methods (such as `.find`) require arguments of type `bytes`.

You could either change `br1_string` to a `bytes` object:

```
br1_string = b"<!-- Data starts here -->"
```

or, decode the response:

```
website_html = website.read().decode()
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation, it takes a bytes-like object or an int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.find).

There are two types here: `str` and `bytes`. Both have a `.find` method. It is easy to mistake them. Your `website_html` file is actually `bytes`, not `str`.